# How to save + close file when editing in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, vi

OK - I am linux newbie - I am trying to edit a file from bash via `edit <filename>` command in whatever the default mode is (I am assuming 'vi'?).

Problem is for the hell of me I cannot how to save and out of edit mode - [this cheatsheet](https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=http://www.catonmat.net/download/bash-vi-editing-mode-cheat-sheet.pdf) seems to suggest ESC should do the trick but it doesn't seem to work.

I am connecting via ssh from a mac to a linux suse enterprise 11 box.

Any help appreciated!

Comment: Additionally I would setup some aliases in your .bashrc if you plan to continue using edit so you can specify which editor is used when using the edit command.  Personally I just type in vim preceeding a file that I want to edit but to each their own.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

<kbd>Esc</kbd> will only throw you back into command mode in VI or Vim.  To Save and quit press <kbd>Shift</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd> + <kbd>Z</kbd>, <kbd>:wq</kbd>, or <kbd>:x</kbd> in command mode.  If you are opening the file in read only mode you will have to hit <kbd>:q!</kbd>.

Consider looking at this cheatsheet as well for more macros [VI cheatsheet](http://www.worldtimzone.com/res/vi.html)

Comment: `:wq` to quit and save.

Comment: `:x` does the same as `:wq` - but you save one key :)

Comment: `shift + Z` worked for me :)

Answer (score 1):

If you are new to Linux I would suggest using something other than `vi`. For instance, `nano` is fairly user-friendly, although much less powerful. Also, `vim` is a variant of `vi` that has some more features (like syntax highlighting) and is slightly easier to use.

Answer (score 0):

In the bash to save the code press esc after esc press the con+x and the alert of do you want to save will appear press "y" over there and hit the enter button.May this help you..

Answer (score -1):

Hitting the I button will enable you to edit the file
Hit the Esc button to exit edit mode
Then the SHIFT+ZZ or type in :wq to save and exit to command mode